# nested loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, nested

I am currently working on a problem that looks for a low bound and a high bound. The two numbers will define the field of numbers to factor. I have code that finds the factors, but now I need to do the outside loop in order to run through the list. I understand what it needs to do, but I have trouble with the coding itself. (Obviously, you have to run through the list of numbers from low to high). Any help would be great. I have run into trouble when I try to update the "num" variable, which is the low bound, or the number being factored at that point.

```
function calculate(num){
    var int = 2;    
    var num = document.getElementById("num").value;
    var high = document.getElementById("high").value;
    var str = num + ": ";


    if (num <= high){

    for (var i = 2; i <= num; i++){
        if(num % i == 0){
            str += i + ",";

        }
        num++;
    }
    document.getElementById("outputArea").innerHTML = str;
    }

}
```

Currently, it is giving me the factored output of just the low number. So if I input 12, it says:

12: 2, 3, 4, 6, 12

Yes, I am currently trying to get the program to go through EACH number including the low and high and factor each one. In the end, it is to be shown in several lines in a textarea tag.

Like this:

12: 2,3,4,6,12,
13: 1, 13
etc....

Comment: Which result should the code produce and what does your current version produce? Pleas provide example input/output.

Comment: @FelixKling - I think It's trying to solve P vs NP, can you solve it for us ?

Comment: I guess I just don't understand what you are trying to do with the code. Do you want to iterate over every number from `low` to `high` and factor each one of them? And if yes, what do you want to do with the result? Maybe I'm missing something really obvious...

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want to do is something like this:

```
var num = 12;
var high = 15;

var str = '';

while (num <= high) {
    str += num + ": ";
    for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            str += i + ",";
        }
    }
    str += '\n';
    num++;
    alert(str);
}
```

which shows:

```
12: 1,2,3,4,6,12,
13: 1,13,
14: 1,2,7,14,
15: 1,3,5,15,
```

The main immediate problem in your code was the wrong placement of num++

A bigger problem is for me to fathom what you think you'll achieve with that algorythm, but that's another story altogether.

For further information, you might want to read articles such as [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization).